# Upgrading from Sharepoint Foundation 2010 to Sharepoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade from Sharepoint Foundation to the full version (SharePoint Server 2010)?  We've half way implemented a site in Foundation and are running into issues.  Can we just install the full version on top of foundation and have it "upgrade" to the new version?  Or will we lose work and have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to upgrade it over itself, install a test box real quick and try it out.

however, don't expect issues to resolve themselves, i suggest resolving any errors before introducing a whole new level of complexity.

Comment: Agree, I have done this successfully. Run the installer and then run the Configuration Wizard to do the upgrade. But don't forget to do backups first ;-)

Comment: Is backing up the SQL database sufficient?